# What should I use sync HTML5 Video with Content

Tags: html, video

I want to display different context-sensitive content during a video playing on a website. I am using HTML5 video and need a JavaScript API to handle eventing. I will need to control the video player as well as react to different time intervals in the video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org) is an open source JavaScript library for programming rich interactive experiences with HTML5 Video and Audio elements and provides a very simply API to "display different context-sensitive content during a video playing on a website".

Take a look at the demo gallery here: http://popcornjs.org/demos

Here is a tutorial, build with Popcorn.js, that shows how to create a simple Popcorn.js program: http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-101

The docs can be found here: http://popcornjs.org/api (this is still in progress)

The following example uses the Popcorn Footnote plugin to display a simple message under the video at specific time in during the playback:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Popcorn Simple Example</title> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script> 

  <script> 
  $(document).bind( "ready", function(){
      // Create a popcporn instance by calling Popcorn("#id-of-my-video")
    var pop = Popcorn("#video");


    // add a footnote at 2 seconds
    pop.footnote({
          start: 2,
          end: 6,
          text: "This footnote is the stepping stone of progress!",
          target: "footnote-container"
        });

    // play the video right away
    pop.play();

  });
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <video height="180" width="300" id="video" controls> 
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.mp4"></source> 
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv"></source> 
  <source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.webm"></source> 
  </video> 


<div id="footnote-container"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/6PEU8/

A recent demo shows how you could use an audio element as a slideshow controller, here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/DjmLM/

Comment: Amazing, Popcorn.js is exactly what I was looking for!